# React DatePicker and Logging to Console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form in which I am using react-datePicker to allow a user to select their birthday. The component sits inside of a form. However, when my form is submitted I have not been able to log the selected birthdate to the console.

Here is some of the form code with the DatePicker component:

```
const Register = () => {
    const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState (true) 
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm ();
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date()); 
    const handleCalendarClose = () => console.log(date);
    const handleCalendarOpen = () => console.log("Calendar opened");
    const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data); 

    const [passwordShown, setPasswordShown] = useState(false);
    const togglePasswordVisiblity = () => {
        setPasswordShown(passwordShown ? false : true);
      };

    return(
        <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen} onRequestClose={() => setModalIsOpen(false)} className='createBorder'>
<form> 
<p className='fieldsOne'>First name:</p>
                <input name='firstName' ref={register({required: true})} className='inputs' autoComplete='off'></input>
                <p className='minifields'>This information will display on your profile</p>
                {errors.firstName && <span className='registerRequired'>This field is required</span>}
                <p className='fields'>Last name:</p>
                <input name='lastName' ref={register({required: true})} className='inputs' autoComplete='off'></input>
                <p className='minifields'>This information will display on your profile</p>
                {errors.lastName && <span className='registerRequired'>This field is required</span>}
                <p className='fields'>Birthdate:</p>
                {/* datepicker is not logged to the console because it is not an input field it is a component, how can we wrap the component */}
                    <DatePicker
                        ref={register({required: true})}
                        dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
                        selected={date}
                        name='Birthday'
                        onChange={date => setDate(date)}
                        onCalendarClose={handleCalendarClose}
                        onCalendarOpen={handleCalendarOpen}
                        />           
                <p className='minifields'>We'll use this information when considering what films you are qualified to test</p>
                {errors.Birthdate && <span className='registerRequired'>This field is required</span>}
</form> 
<div className='alignalign'>
                <a href='/GetStarted/completeProfile' onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} type='submit' className='signupButton'>Sign Up</a>
            </div>
</Modal>
```

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever data that is not included in the from data you just simply add it to the data object while processing.

```
 const onSubmit = (data) => {data['birthdate']= date; console.log(data);}
```